# How Can I remove a record from KafkaStreams PersistentKeyValueStore?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I put some records to a PersistentKeyValueStore:

```
Long nowValue = Optional.ofNullable(myStore.get(key)).orElse(0L) + newValue;
myStore.put(key, nowValue);
```

It runs well. I can see the records through println:

```
KeyValueIterator<String, Long> iter = myStore.all();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
     KeyValue<String, Long> entry = iter.next();
     System.out.println(entry.value)
}
iter.close();
```

But when i try to remove a record:

```
KeyValueIterator<String, Long> iter = myStore.all();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
     iter.remove();
}
iter.close();
```

It goes to exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RocksDB iterator does not support remove()
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore$RocksDbIterator.remove(RocksDBStore.java:515)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.InnerMeteredKeyValueStore$MeteredKeyValueIterator.remove(InnerMeteredKeyValueStore.java:306)
    at com.loogtech.bi.compute.realtime.processor.AddCashProcessor$TotalCashAddPunctuator.punctuate(AddCashProcessor.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$4.run(ProcessorNode.java:131)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.punctuate(ProcessorNode.java:134)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.punctuate(StreamTask.java:263)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PunctuationQueue.mayPunctuate(PunctuationQueue.java:54)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.maybePunctuateSystemTime(StreamTask.java:619)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.punctuate(AssignedTasks.java:430)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.punctuate(TaskManager.java:324)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.punctuate(StreamThread.java:969)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:834)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:774)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:744)
```

It seems can't remove record also by `myStore.remove(key)`

How can i remove a record by key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interface `KeyValueStore` provides a `#delete(...)` method (not `#remove(...)`) to delete records from a store.

Comment: I keep the topic data two days. Is the store data saved in topic? Can it be deleted auto after two days?

Comment: The default KeyValueStore has no data retention time. You would need to store the timestamp explicitly and delete data manually if you want. If you implement your own KeyValueStore and plug it in. And yes, KeyValueStore data is by default backed by an additional topic that is configured with log-compaction (no retention time).